# Rewriting app MVC style

Tags: java, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, javabeans

I have a working java beans application with 3 fields, where field one sets limit of modulo after subtracting field 3 from field 2. Everything was working fine but now I was informed that my app should be rewritten to MVC where 3 inputs are also views. So question is - what to move where ? And what should be the model ?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
    public Main(){
        Values val1 = new Values();
        Values val2 = new Values();
        Limitator changer = new Limitator(val1, val2);
        Values val3 = new Values();
        Input in1 = new Input();
        Input in2 = new Input();
        Input in3 = new Input();
        val1.addPropertyChangeListener(in1);
        val2.addPropertyChangeListener(in2);
        val3.addPropertyChangeListener(changer);
        val1.addVetoableChangeListener(changer);
        val2.addVetoableChangeListener(changer);
        GUI frame = new GUI(in1, in2, in3, val1, val2, val3);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main argh = new Main();
    }
}

class Input extends JTextField implements PropertyChangeListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Input(){
        this("0");
    }

    public Input(String txt){
        super(txt);
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Integer newVal = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
        setText("" + newVal);
    }
}

class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Values val1;
    private Values val2;
    private Values val3;
    private Input in1;
    private Input in2;
    private Input in3;

    public GUI(Input in1, Input in2, Input in3, Values val1, Values val2, Values val3){
        this.setTitle("Beansy!");
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 110));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        this.val3 = val3;
        this.in1 = in1;
        this.in2 = in2;
        this.in3 = in3;
        Container con = new Container();
        con.setLayout(new BoxLayout(con, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        in1.addActionListener(this);
        in2.addActionListener(this);
        in3.addActionListener(this);
        con.add(in1);
        con.add(in2);
        con.add(in3);
        this.add(con);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int tmp = 0;
        if(e.getSource()==in1){
            try{
                    tmp = Integer.parseInt(in1.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numbers only!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in1.setText(val1.getValue()+"");
            }
            try {
                    val1.setValue(tmp);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in1.setText(val1.getValue()+"");
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==in2){
            try{
                tmp = Integer.parseInt(in2.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numbers only!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in2.setText(val2.getValue()+"");
            }
            try {
                val2.setValue(tmp);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in2.setText(val2.getValue()+"");
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==in3){
            try{
                tmp = Integer.parseInt(in3.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Numbers only!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in3.setText(val3.getValue()+"");
            }
            try {
                val3.setValue(tmp);
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                in3.setText(val3.getValue()+"");
            }
        }
    }
}

class Values implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int val = 0;
    private VetoableChangeSupport veto = new VetoableChangeSupport(this);
    private PropertyChangeSupport prop = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public Values(){
        this(0);
    }

    public Values(int val){
        try {
            setValue(val);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error when initializing", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener prop_nu) {
        this.prop.addPropertyChangeListener(prop_nu);
    }

    public synchronized void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener prop) {
        this.prop.removePropertyChangeListener(prop);
    }

    public void addVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener veto){
        this.veto.addVetoableChangeListener(veto);
    }

    public void removeVetoableChangeListener(VetoableChangeListener veto){
        this.veto.removeVetoableChangeListener(veto);
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.val;
    }

    public synchronized void forceValue(int val){
        int oldValue = this.val;
        this.val = val;
        prop.firePropertyChange("Value", new Integer(oldValue), new Integer(val));
    }

    public synchronized void setValue(int val) throws PropertyVetoException{
        int oldValue = this.val;
        veto.fireVetoableChange("Value", new Integer(oldValue), new Integer(val));
        this.val = val;
        prop.firePropertyChange("Value", new Integer(oldValue), new Integer(val));
    }
}

class Limitator implements VetoableChangeListener, PropertyChangeListener{
    int range;
    Values val1;
    Values val2;

    public Limitator(){
        this(0, null, null);
    }

    public Limitator(int num){
        this(num, null, null);
    }

    public Limitator(Values val1, Values val2) {
        this(0,val1,val2);
    }

    public Limitator(int num, Values val1, Values val2) {
        this.range = num;
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0)throws PropertyVetoException {
        int nu_val = (Integer)arg0.getNewValue();
        int ol_val = (Integer)arg0.getOldValue();
        int another_val;

        if(arg0.getSource()==val1){
            another_val = val2.getValue();
        }else{
            another_val = val1.getValue();
        }

        if(Math.abs(another_val - nu_val) > range){
            if(arg0.getSource()==val1){
                val1.forceValue(ol_val);
            }
            else if(arg0.getSource()==val2){
                val2.forceValue(ol_val);
            }
            throw new PropertyVetoException("Limit exceeded!!", arg0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        int new_range = ((Integer)evt.getNewValue()).intValue();
        this.range = new_range;
    }
}
```

Comment: "And what should be the model ?" Ask yourself this: if I had to port this app to another UI (e.g. web-based), would I have to scrap the whole code?  Are there parts of the code I could still use? Could I reorganize the code so that if I had to port to yet another UI, it would be easier next time?

Comment: good questions. Problem is that there is no true model here. Only thing I can think of is some wrapper for the Limiter and Values.

Comment: Here's an MVC example that may suggest an approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979

Answer (score 1):

Here's some information that should help, without giving you the exact code:

Basically, the reasoning behind using the MVC design pattern is to separate the logic from the UI. The three parts can be briefly described as:

**Model:** The core logic of the program.

**View(s):** Bits of the UI that utilize the model (logic) to display the right info.

**Controller(s):** It's easiest to think of the controller as the ActionListeners for your View.

The "Model" and the "View(s)" are nearly always separate classes; the "Controller" is often incorporated into the View(s), since it sometimes simply consists of adding ActionListeners.

Here's an example of a *very basic* application of using MVC to make a simple program cleaner. Suppose we have a basic calculator, defined by the following interface:

```
public class Calc {
   public int add(int[] nums) {}
   public int sub(int[] nums) {}
   public int mult(int[] nums) {}
   public double div(int[] nums) {}
}
```

And a GUI for that calculator, CalcGUI. So, our goal is to keep the model separate from the view. We could use the MVC and so something like this...

```
public class CalcGUI extends JFrame {
   private Calc model;
   private JTextField result;
   public CalcGUI(Calc model) {
      this.model = model;
      // Random GUI setup stuff
      result = new JTextField(10);
      ... whatever else you need
      // Add controllers
   }
   // A sample view method that uses the model for logic
   public void add() {
      result.setText(model.add(user's numbers));
   }
}
```

Notice how the GUI doesn't need to use any logic in-terms of the program's functionality (math operations). The "model" Calc object does all the logic for the GUI (view); all the GUI needs to do is call on the model's methods and use its return values to display the proper information to the user.

Another important thing to note is the CalcGUI constructor. Notice how it takes in a "Calc" object. Since Objects are pointers in Java (referenced by memory address), the same "Calc" object will always be used. This is important if you need to store information in your model (not the case in this app, but almost always the case in a 'real' app).\

**Some Helpful Links for Learning the MVC:**

http://www.enode.com/x/markup/tutorial/mvc.html

http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/mvcdesignpattern.html

http://cristobal.baray.com/indiana/projects/mvc.html

I hope that helped!